# @angular/material datepicker position

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using @angular/material2 module to add datepicker to my angular 4 app.

here is my HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

app.module.ts

```
import {MatDatepickerModule,MatNativeDateModule,MatFormFieldModule,MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
```

when I click on the datepicker toggler the datepicker popup is opened at the very end of the page completely outside the form field it should be opened at.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing part was to import the CSS file `angular-material.css`

Comment: this stylesheet worked for me : **node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt_themes/indigo_pink.css** worked for me

Answer (score 11):

My problem was I had set `.mat-form-field-underline` to hidden. The date picker uses this element to determine position.

Comment: You have saved me so much time trying to figure out what was wrong!

Comment: .simple-hidden { visibility: hidden; width: 0;  z-index: -1; } https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9730#issuecomment-378976192

Answer (score 9):

If you use the `touchUi="true"` on the `<matDatepicker>` component it appears as a modal. Not sure if your site is going to be mostly used on mobile but I find this appearance for the matDatepicker to be more desired.

Here is the markup:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Birthday" [formControl]="birthday">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #picker></mat-datepicker> //This line has the touchUi
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really nice solution. My problem was the datepicker was cut of at the top of the screen so was not fully visible. Your solution to display it as a overlay is way more appealing too I think.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same issue with Angular 4 with Material 2 Datepicker.

Somehow **node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css** is not getting linked in application. I fixed it by copying the content of this style sheet in my root style sheet 'style.css'.

Add or link this style sheet in your project: **node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css**

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that I had more than one <mat-datepicker #mydate> with #mydate name. I changed the names and it works!

Answer (score 0):

This problem may also occur if you hide the `<input matInput` (for whatever reason).

If you must hide the input, then don't need use `display: none` because it would be impossible to calculate the position of the calendar. Use `visibility: hidden` instead or set the input width and height to 0, etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

You need create function click ex:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()" placeholder="Choose a date">
```

Comment: the popup is open by `mat-datepicker-toggle` this is not my issue, please check my question again

Answer (score -2):

Ups sory man, you need add css style, position: relative;
mat-datepicker-toggle {position: relative;} or you parent, good luck